# BLUE SCREEN after logging on a freshly installed bone 16.04

Tags: boot, uefi, bios

I reinstalled UBUNTU 16.04 via the official iso burned to DVD on my Lenovo laptop (I am not simple boot) The installation ends as planned, I launch ubuntu, until then by problem, I make 5 updates via Ubuntu softawre. I restart the computer, I enter password to access my Ubuntu session and there: bulk pixels, then BLUE screen! My mouse disappears, appears, in short, I can not acceder my session and the terminal does not work.

I run the trial version of Ubuntu in live cd to have access to BOOT REPAIR as indicated in this forum: https://forum.ubuntu-fr.org/viewtopic.php?id=1998775

I install it as expected, I restart the computer and I see that the Grub is displayed, so far no. But at the level of the blue screen it is the same ... I can not access my Ubuntu session.

Also, I tried to reinstalled 16.04 a second time. during the installation I got this message:

The microcode of this system has started the installer in UEFI mode but there seem to be other operating systems that use the BIOS compatibility mode. If you continue the installation in UEFI mode, it may be difficult to restart these operating systems at a later time.
If you want to retain the ability to restart other installed systems; you should NOT (in uppercase in the text) force the installation into UEFI mode.
https://forum.ubuntu-fr.org/viewtopic.php?id=1992570

Anyone know more?

LAM

Comment: En anglais s'il vous plaît, les règles du site.